# Is there a way to get hourly data from Facebook Insights Graph/FQL api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-insights

Facebook only sends day, week, month and lifetime data. The only way I see is to get data every hour, but that doesn't work for past queries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not possible to get finer insights data period breakdown than by day from the Graph/FQL APIs. Only day, week, month or lifetime data aggregations are available, as specified in the [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/) and [Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/) Developer pages. Even though the FQL table's end_time field takes an hour-specific point in time expressed in unix time, that hour has to be set to midnight, Pacific Daylight Time, effectively making it a request for daily data as minimum period.

There are real-time analytics for social-plugins and Pages, but it is not accessible as raw data and has to be viewed through the Facebook dashboard. Last year, FB introduced [real-time analytics for Social Plugins](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/476/) on Websites, such as the Like Button and the Comments box. FB has recently this year started offering [real-time data for Pages](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/facebook/facebook-announces-real-time-page-insights/9769). Again, it's only viewable online on your Page's insights section.

Comment: Its odd they've real time data for page posts, but not for page, maybe in the near future. Thx for your answer.

Comment: Glad the answer was of some help. Yes, it's curious they don't offer more real-time data or hourly data through the API...